# using index and match to populate a calendar

Tags: excel, indexing, calendar, match

I am trying to populate the calendar i have built below from a table on `sheet 2` only visible by myself. As i need it to look at the employee and the date i  tryed using `{=INDEX(Table1[Column1],MATCH(Calendar!A7&Calendar!B6,Table1[Employee]&Table1[Date],0))}`
 but this keeps returning `#VALUE!`. The only explanation i can find is that is the date. I have combined the 2 cells using `=A7&B6` and the value is "Employee142491" i have done the same against my table and again i get the same value. As they are a direct match in value i cant see the reason why it wont work.

Can anybody please offer some advice.

[image]

Comment: Where is your table1, in Sheet2? Anyways, you need to add a column which combines the employee and date there. `Match(what, RANGE, matchtype)`. so it needs to be a single Range

Comment: What value are looking to get out of the formula you have provided?

Comment: @Sun I have used this method and it works perfectly. I have created a table of sheet that combines the employee and the date and then used these values for the `MATCH` formula. Thank you for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the `Match` function in your `Index` formula with:

```
SUMPRODUCT(ROW(Table1[Employee])*(Table1[Employee]=Calendar!A7)*(Table1[Date]=Calendar!B6))
```

This way you don't need to concatenate.

However you may need to add or subtract a number of rows depending on where Table1 is on the worksheet.